# Interrupt child called from ruby

Tags: ruby

Why interrupting ruby process with child created using call to `system` does not interrupt ruby process itself? They should belong to the same group, so should be both interrupted. Also this is not valid for ruby2.0.

Given ruby 1.8.7 patch 371, ruby 1.9.3 patch 392 and ruby2.0 patch 0:

Running `ruby1.8 -e 'system "sleep 100"; p $?; sleep'` in bash and pressing ⌃C kills only inner call to `sleep 100`.

Ruby 1.9 behaves identically.

Though running `ruby2.0 -e 'system "sleep 100"; p $?; sleep'` interrupts both inner command and ruby process itself.2.0.0-p0

**--EDIT--**

Reading sources I've found that handling `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT` and `SIGHUP` is switched to ignored in `rb_syswait` method which than waits for created sub process to finish and then restores handlers (`rb_syswait` in [ruby v1.8.7-p370](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?v=1.8.7-p370;i=rb_syswait), [ruby v1.9.3-p362](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?v=1.9.3-p362;i=rb_syswait) and without blocking handlers in [ruby v2.0.0-p0](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?v=2.0.0-p0;i=rb_syswait)).

Why is it done and why only for `system` and `IO.popen`, not `%x{}` or `fork{}`?

Comment: Do you want to know implementation details or how to work-around this?

Comment: @SemyonPerepelitsa: both + what should be considered normal behaviour

Comment: @SemyonPerepelitsa now only why is it done and best workarounds

Answer (score 1):

For a workaround, you can propagate SIGINT yourself.  You can examine whether the system command exited due to a signal, and if so raise SIGINT:

```
ruby1.8 -e 'system "sleep 100"; p $?; Process.kill("INT",0) if $?.signaled?; sleep'
```

Comment: Does not help if process is handling interrupts:
`ruby1.8 -e 'system %q{ruby1.8 -e "Signal.trap(%q{INT}){exit}; sleep 10"}; p $?; Process.kill("INT",0) if $?.signaled?; sleep'`

Comment: @tig That is true. In that case, you would need some other way (perhaps a special exit code in the child) to indicate that a signal was received by the child process.

Comment: @tig, right, that was just an example. This was just a workaround, after all ... I don't think there is a workaround that is going to be usable in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

This does not seem to be an question of Ruby but your operating system, which you did not specify.  Process grouping and low-level system routing is done by the OS kernel.

Comment: Difference is in ruby, please compare source code at provided links

Comment: Run both commands under `strace` and compare the outputs.  Perhaps, `setpgid` is called in one case and not the other?